# Locus of the mid point of a line segment

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

Problem:

> A rod of length $2$ units moves so that its ends are on the positive $x$-axis and on the line $x+y=0$ which lies in the second quadrant. Find the locus of the midpoint of the rod.

My approach:

Let the midpoint be $P(h,k).$ Let the end on the $x$-axis have coordinates $(x_2,0$). The end on $x+y=0$ has coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$.
$$\Rightarrow 2h=x_1+x_2$$
$$\Rightarrow 2k=y_1$$
$$\Longrightarrow 2h+2k=x_2$$

I cannot eliminate $x_2$ from the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not used the information of the length of the rod yet. That gives you
$$(x_2-x_1)^2+(0-y_1)^2=4$$

If you plug $x_2=2h+2k, x_1=-2k , y_1=2k$ into this, you will find an equation about $h,k$.

Answer (score 0):

If we let parameter $t$ vary from 0 to 2,
following $x$-coordinate 
of the right end of the rod $R_t=(t,0)$,
then the left end has coordinates
$L_t=(-s,s)$, where $s$ can be found from

\begin{align}
2^2&=s^2+(t+s)^2,
\\
s&=\tfrac12(\sqrt{8-t^2}-t)
\end{align}
Thus coordinates of the midpoint $M$ in terms of $t$ are
\begin{align}
M_x&=\tfrac14(3 t-\sqrt{8-t^2}),
\\
M_y&=\tfrac14(-t+\sqrt{8-t^2}).
\end{align}

We can also exclude $t$ and get
\begin{align}
y(x)&=\tfrac15\left(\sqrt{5-x^2}-2x\right),\quad x\in[-\tfrac{\sqrt2}2,1].
\end{align}